# ORA-00972 : An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified while creating an alias name

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

In my SQL queries I am concatenating all the table column values with a pipe delimiter and adding the column names(pipe delimted) as  alias.
It says An identifier with more than 30 characters was specified.
Is there any alternative for this.

```
select '' || '|' || tablename.field1 || '|' ||  tablename.field2 || '|' || as
"columname1 | columname2  | columname3 
        | columname4 | columname5 | columname6 | columname7 | columname8 |  columname9 | "
```

Comment: Oracle limits column names to 30 characters. Use a shorter name.

Comment: Perhaps you're used to Oracle 12.2, which allows identifiers with up to 128 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a viable work-around for you, since you will have a blank header to deal with, but you might try:

```sql
    SELECT 'columname1 | columname2  | columname3 
        | columname4 | columname5 | columname6 | columname7 | columname8 |  columname9 | ' 
    AS " "
    UNION
    SELECT '' || '|' || tablename.field1 || '|' ||  tablename.field2 || '|' ||
```

I don't have access to Oracle, but it works with SQL-Server and provides a blank column name above the piped name record.

**UPDATE:** To clarify: instead of using a long "alias", this query `SELECTs` the string of column names as the "value" in the column with a column name of " " (single space). Then, a `UNION` is used to add the "real" data below this row of a constant string.

Comment: Still more than 30 characters

Comment: @Eric, no. The alias is set to a single space `" "`. The first `SELECT` in the `UNION` is simply replacing the OP's alias with a string constant as the value in the column, then I used the `UNION` to add the table data below this string constant. So there is no > 30 character alias here.